# py.test freezes after collecting items

Tags: python-3.x, freeze, pytest

$ py.test -x
========================================== test session starts ==========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.4.2 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
collecting 39 items

and then nothing. Well except that is consumes quite a lot of processor power.

Comment: Can you try running test-by-test (using -k test_name) to see if this caused by any single test, or by fixture?

Comment: It was a single test and the fault was in my code where the test triggered an infinit loop :-(